# React Leaflet, show tooltip on mouseover on a cluster icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

i need to show a tooltip (with the child information) on mouseover on a cluster.

For example in this image, when i go over the green cluster i want to show a tooltip whit some information.

[img react leaflet map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7TQY.png)

I use

"**react**": "^16.9.0",

"**reactstrap**": "^8.0.1"

"**leaflet**": "^1.6.0"

"**react-leaflet**": "^2.6.1"

"**react-leaflet-markercluster**": "^2.0.0-rc3"*

The code of this part:

```
<MarkerClusterGroup showCoverageOnHover={true} onmouseover={(e)= (console.log(e.sourceTarget._markers))}>            
 <Marker position={[44.982963, 7.707891]} id="aabb"/>
 <Marker position={[49.839778, 24.029721]} id="ccdd"/>
 <Marker position={[52.229758, 21.012236]} id="eeff"/>
 <Marker position={[51.507466, -0.090148]} id="gghh"/>
</MarkerClusterGroup>
```

Whith the *onmouseover={(e)= (console.log(e.sourceTarget._markers))* i can access at the information, like marker id.

Thabk you!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use a map on markers array, so:

```
<MarkerClusterGroup
  onMouseOver={(e) => {
    e.propagatedFrom.bindTooltip(`Markers: ${markers.length}`).openTooltip();
  }}
  onMouseOut={(e) => {
    e.propagatedFrom.unbindTooltip();
  }}>
  {markers.map((marker)=> 
   (<Marker position={[marker.lat, marker.lon]}>
    ..... 
    </Marker>))}
 </MarkerClusterGroup>}
```

Comment: Yes, but i want the tooltip on the cluster icon, not on the marker icon...

Comment: Sorry, now I edit my response ... is what you need?

Comment: Ok, but... i want to show in a frontend view (like tooltip) this console log information...

Comment: Ok, thank you for this step.. but now i see the tooltip both in the cluster and in the marker... Basically i need two kind of tooltip, one the tootlitp cluster (like this) and one a classic tooltip for the marker. I use <Tooltip> component for the markers, but the <MarkerClusterGroup> overrides all

Comment: Sincerely I think is not a good thing to do that, because you use the cluster not like they suggest; so your code could be not work in the future. The best thing could be rebuild your custom cluster :-D  I hope I helped you

Comment: Ok, thank you... Any tips for make a custom Cluster components?

Comment: It is a complex and well done copmponent. I suggest to start here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster   :-D

Comment: Ok thank you! It's possible to style the tooltip and pop? (ex change background color, font, ecc)??

Comment: I don't know, perhaps with some override styles, but is very dangerous to do...I suggest again to do something custom